# 'clear' doesn't clean the screen when I run docker on Windows Command Prompt

Tags: windows, docker

I am using docker on windows with an Ubuntu Image. Everything is just fine on docker itself, but when I run one of those images, whenever I try to clean the screen, the cursor moves to the fist line but all of the others line are still there.

The screen looks very weird..
Is there any fix or walkaround?

Comment: That's how clear works.

Comment: no, definitely not, you must be misunderstanding

Answer (score 1):

you just need to hit the `ctrl+c` and you will be redirected to the local location and than you type `clear`.
Hope done so your question and it will be helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

1. Go outside of the docker ( to your base system) and check $TERM on that system
   with `echo $TERM`. Note the output of that.
2. Now go inside the docker and check if it is the same. If not make it same
   by using the command export `TERM = "your output"` such as linux, xterm, etc.